# created thread doesn't get executed

Tags: linux, pthreads

here I come again with a new question for this (blasted) threads programming.
Here is my code, hope you can help me understand what's wrong with it (keep in mind I had to write this code again, not copy-paste, so there may be some type errors - the compiled code is ok and works, so the problem is not the syntax).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>

int i=0;

void *TFun(void *TArg)
{
printf("THREAD    i=%d\n", i);
i++;
return NULL;
}

int main()
{
pthread_t TID;

TID=pthread_create(&TID, NULL, TFun, NULL);
pthread_join(TID, NULL);

printf("THREAD    i=%d\n", i);
i++;

exit(0);
}
```

I expect this to print "THREAD    i=0" and then "MAIN    i=1", but this doesn't happen. it only prints "MAIN    i=0", the Thread is not executed.

https://i.ibb.co/Y0KYWCK/code.png
https://i.ibb.co/pznZ3TT/result.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The value of TID is normally written by reference within `pthread_create()`, but was also being overwritten with the `int` return value; change to an added `int` variable:

(old)

```
TID=pthread_create(&TID, NULL, TFun, NULL);
```

(new)

```
int pcr;
pcr = pthread_create(&TID, NULL, TFun, NULL);
```

Comment: ... The key point being that because the `TID` value was corrupted, the `pthread_join` call was ineffective.  Moreover, the OP would have know that `pthread_join` was failing  if they had taken care to check that function's return value.